# the need for tokens in temporary credentials, amazon s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, security, amazon-s3

I was looking into the Amazon S3 documentation and I realized that when a permanent IAM user would be added, an AccessID and a SecretID would be generated. However, when a temporary user would be added, an AccessID, a SecretID and a token would be generated. This token would have to be passed as a parameter in the ensuing requests. The details can be found [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingTemporarySecurityCredentials_SDB.html).

Why exactly are tokens used? What is the need/usecase that it satisfies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see the Amazon documentation on [Use Cases for Granting Temporary Access](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/STSUseCases.html)?

I've used this sort of temporary access with a music service to grant web and mobile users temporary access to music files stored on S3.  I generated a custom url for users for each S3 file -- the URL would expired immediately, so it couldn't be shared with others.